# How can I call a template from an inherited form view in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, erp

I am a beginner to Odoo 8.

I want to use the template *(template id = "Variants")* that is in the `website_sale` module in the form view of "Order lines" that has an `external_id` *(ref="sale.view_order_form")*.

so I made inheritance like this:

```
<record id="multiple_variante_sale_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
         <field name="model">sale.order</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field/form/group/group/field[@name='product_id']" position="after">


                 -- here I want to call the template of the wesite_sale <template id="Variants" > --


            </xpath>
         </field>
```

Can I do this? If yes, how?